# Web Service doesn't write logs when called from Tablet

Tags: vb.net, web-services

There's a web service set up that our application is calling.

When calling this function through a browser (Tested using Mozilla Firefox), this function writes to the log file correctly (with the values that we provide to it). However, when calling this function through a tablet (tested on the same network and on a different network), nothing is written to the logs.

It's simple, looks like this:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function CreateClient( _
    ByVal strUserID As String, _
    ByVal strVehicleID As String, _
    ByVal strUnit As String, _
    ByVal strHouse As String, _
    ByVal strStreet As String, _
    ByVal strCity As String, _
    ByVal strContactName As String, _
    ByVal strPhone As String, _
    ByVal strComments As String)

    Dim strReturn As String = "14"

    Dim strLog As String = ""
    strLog = "CreateClient strUserID = " & strUserID & ", strVehicleID = " & strVehicleID & ", strUnit = " & strUnit & ", strHouse = " & strHouse & ", strStreet = " & strStreet & ", strCity = " & strCity
    strLog &= ", strContactName=" & strContactName & ", strPhone=" & strPhone & ", strComments=" & strComments

    Class1.WriteLogEntry(strLog, Class1.LOG_TYPE_DEBUG)

    Return strReturn
End Function
```

We know we're reaching and calling the correct web service & function because when we change the return value, the tablet shows the correct value after each deployment. Eg: when the return value is set to "1", the tablet gets back a "1", and after changing it to a "14", the tablet also gets back a "14".

**Does anyone know why the logs are not being written, and/or how to fix this?**

Note: If you need to see the android code for how we're calling it, I'll post it, but again, I don't think it's necessary since we already know that we're calling it properly and getting the correct return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the problem was, but after changing 2 things, the logs started working again:

- Moved all the code from `Class1` to a Module (`Module`)
- Changed the target file it was saving to.

Could it be possible that there was something else locking onto the file, thus preventing this log from being written? Or perhaps Classes and Modules don't have the same file writing permissions?